# In AWS Cloudformation, is it possible to set a wildcard for LogGroupName for AWS::Logs::LogGroup?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have many Lambdas and I would like to set the log retention policy in AWS Cloudformation using AWS::Logs::LogGroup for all of them, but the only examples I have seen set LogGroupName for each one.  Is it possible to set a retention policy for all Lambdas logs using a wildcard or without having to specify each Lambda function?

I tried this:

```
LambdaLogGroup:    
  Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup    
  Properties:    
    LogGroupName: '/aws/lambda/*'    
    RetentionInDays: 14
```

However, this fails to deploy (stack fails) unsurprisingly with the following error: ["Model validation failed (#/LogGroupName: failed validation constraint for keyword [pattern])"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-logs-loggroup.html).

I also tried:

```
LambdaLogGroup:
  Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup
  Properties:
    LogGroupName: /aws/lambda/
    RetentionInDays: 14
```

However, that only sets the policy for the top, not for any individual Lambda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly its **not possible** in plain CFN. You would have to do it using [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) in CloudFormation.